# How to read a repetead tag in a xml with pentaho?

Tags: xml, pentaho, etl

I am trying to load and XML file with pentaho:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<scapplication>
<heading>
  <dispatchingcode>GML</dispatchingcode>
  <version>001</version>
  <dispatchingcompany>1232</dispatchingcompany>
</heading>
<F456>
  <reqcode>0019682125</reqcode>
  <comreferencenum>30104</comreferencenum>
  <responsedate>2017-06-29</responsedate>
</F456>
<F456>
  <reqcode>0019657723</reqcode>
  <comreferencenum>29676</comreferencenum>
  <responsedate>2017-06-29</responsedate>
</F456>
</scapplication>
```

The main problem that I found loading this with pentaho is that F456 tag should be iterated in the load.
This means that I need to detect every node inside every F456 node because later I will load this in two different rows in a table output statement.

How can be readed both tags in a loop with pentaho?
I guess that if both tags were inside another one it would be easy but I do not have a tag above these two, so I do not know how to load with `GET DATA FROM XML Step`

I tried seeting F456 as a field in the step and set repeat option as Y. But it does not works...

Answer (score 1):

If you use **/scapplication/F456** as your XPath loop node, you will get one record per F456 node and using "Get Fields" will get you the child elements as fields.

Assuming there is only one [heading] section per [scapplication], you can manually enter the additional fields to get them for each record:

```
Name           |XPath                     |Element |Result type |Type
dispatchingcode|../heading/dispatchingcode|Node    |Value of    |String
```

Answer (score 0):

@Maik You can use stax parser and load into tables using switch and de-normalizer. Preview the data in stax parser component . Understand xml_element_id, xml_parent_element_id in preview. Let me know if you want any help on this. Design Parent and child tables using xml_element_id, xml_parent_element_id. Identify the column which you want to keep in Parent and child both. Then update the values i child tables using xml_element_id, xml_parent_element_id.